# SQL select statement string concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

Can something like this be done with a select statement:

```
SELECT col1, concat(col2 + ' ') FROM ....
       GROUP BY col1
```

I know i can use count(col2) or sum(col2) for integers but is there a function for concatenating if the type is nvarchar or nchar?

Comment: Yes, but depends on which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Forgot to mention that i am using Microsoft SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, if you want to concatenate across rows, there is no built in function to do this.

I personally like [using XML PATH](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) as it seems to perform well, but this will work only in SQL Server 2005 onwards

```
SELECT
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      ' ' + Description
    FROM dbo.Brands
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
  ) As concatenated_string
```

Comment: Tried it out and it works as i need i to.
Thanks for the help :).

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Depending on the query, you may need to bind the resultset that is concatenated inside the `STUFF` function to a field outside of the function using a join, in order to restrict the resultset and hence concatenated string for each result in an outer resultset.

Answer (score 1):

The [+ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28SQL.80%29.aspx) is used to concatenate strings in T-SQL.

EDIT:

If you wish to aggregate strings over multiple rows [this might help](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

Comment: The OP wants a Group By aggregate function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sql Server there is no built-in aggregate concatenation foncton, I know MySql has one called group_concat.

Sql Server, you, would either have to write your own scaler funcion, or a CLR function to achieve this.

Or you can use a cursor to do this for you, with a table var to return the results. I can provide an example if you like.