# Vendor agnostic SQL to concatenate field values across records

Tags: sql

I have the following DB Schema :-

[image]

#### Data is ...

```
Location Table
1. New York
2. London
3. Tokyo
4. Melbourne
```

#### OtherNames Table (aka Aliases)

```
1. NYC
1. New York City
4. Home
3. Foo
3. PewPew
```

What I'm trying to do, as SQL, is get the following results :-

> ID, Name, Name + Aliases

eg.

```
1 | New York | new york nyc new york city
2 | London | NULL
3 | Tokyo | tokyo foo pewpew
4 | Melbourne | melbourne home
```

I'm not sure how to get that LAST column.

It's like I want to have a SubQuery which `COALESCE`'s the OtherName.Name field, per Location row... ?

It's related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930442/can-i-create-a-single-string-that-contains-all-the-row-data-for-a-single-field-fr) I have .. but my previous question doesn't give me the proper results I was after (I didn't ask the right question, before :P)

NOTE: I'm after a TSQL / Non server specific answer. So please don't suggest `GROUP_CONCAT();`

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? There are many different ways depending on server version

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server - but i'm hoping for an answer that is independent of the software - some universal sql answer. (which was why I didn't add sql-server-2008 to the tag).

Comment: There is no universal way as such - different rdbms can have built in functions to do it or have different tools in the toolset to provide an RDBMS specific approach. BTW TSQL is SQL Server's dialect of SQL, other rdbms may have their own dialect (not 100% that dialect is the correct term).

Comment: ahhh - so then i better remove the tsql tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL isn't suited to this kind of operation (1NF violation and all that), therefore the various workarounds in SQL will be vendor-specific. If you want something vendor-independent then use something that will consume vanilla SQL (rather than generate it) e.g. a report writer or 3GL application ;)

Comment: can u please elaborate on why this is violating first normal form (1nf)?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: By concatenating multiple (scalar) domain values into a 'list' within a single column you are violating 1NF.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 onwards, I personally like the [XPATH approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851896/sql-select-statement-string-concatenation/1851919#1851919)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link, I'm on iPhone and no longer get the toolbar :(