# Fluent NHibernate - Mapping a multi level class hierarchy

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, subclass, subclassing

I have a legacy database that uses a table per class hierarchy inheritance strategy that uses two database columns as discriminators, usetype and formattype. UseType gives you the top level, formattype the second.

Essentially I would like to be able to populate a class hierarchy like:

```
public abstract class Unknown {}

public abstract class Animal : Unknown { }
public class Lion : Animal {}
public class Lamb : Animal {}

public class Mineral : Unknown { }

public abstract class Vegetable : Unknown {}

public class Rose : Vegetable { }
public class Cabbage : Vegetable {}
```

From data like:

```
| UseType   | FormatType |
--------------------------
| Animal    | Lion       |
| Animal    | Lamb       |
| Mineral   | null       |
| Vegetable | Rose       |
| Vegetable | Cabbage    |
```

I thought I could user Fluent mappings like:

```
public sealed class UnknownMap : ClassMap<Unknown>
{
    public UnknownMap()
    {
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("UseType");
    }
}

public sealed class AnimalMap : SubclassMap<Animal>
{
    public AnimalMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Animal");
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("FormatType");
    }
}

public sealed class LionMap : SubclassMap<Lion>
{
    public LionMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Lion");
    }
}

public sealed class LambMap : SubclassMap<Lamb>
{
    public LambMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Lamb");
    }
}

public sealed class MineralMap : SubclassMap<Mineral>
{
    public MineralMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Mineral");
    }
}

public sealed class VegetableMap : SubclassMap<Vegetable>
{
    public VegetableMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Vegetable");
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("FormatType");
    }
}


public sealed class RoseMap : SubclassMap<Rose>
{
    public RoseMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Rose");
    }
}

public sealed class CabbageMap : SubclassMap<Cabbage>
{
    public CabbageMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Cabbage");
    }
}
```

But unfortunately DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn isn't supported in SubclassMap.

According to the [Fluent NHibernate Wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Subclasses), multi column discriminators are supported through the use of a custom sql statement.

Unfortunately, I have to support a rather large number of subclasses, and I'd really prefer to use something that's compiled with the code. After all, that's why I'm using Fluent NHibernate in the first place.

Comment: I've tried using an aggregate string for the Discriminator (e.g "Animal|Lion"), but unfortunately string concatenation is not vendor agnostic in SQL (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939809/vendor-agnostic-sql-to-concatenate-field-values-across-records").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options for using string concatenation come to my mind:

- generate a storedProcedure for stringconcatenation which can be reimplemented in each DB-System and use a formula to call it
- make the classmap `UnknownMap` database aware

  ```
  public UnknownMap()
  {
      string formula;
      switch (Configuration.GetDbType())
      {
          case DBType.SQLServer:
              formula = "GROUP_CONCAT(UseType, FormatType´)";
              break;
          ...
      }

      DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("")
          .Formula(formula);
  }
  ```

Comment: It looks like you may be right. I've looked at using a big case statement but it's just going to get ugly. Integer discriminators that are bitshifted and added is another option ((usetype * 10000) + formattype).

Comment: @aboy021 nice idea, less readable in database but easier to implement